# Poynting theorem in Landau and Lifshitz’ field theory book

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, classical-field-theory

In Landau & Lifshitz’s [The Classical Theory of Fields](https://books.google.ch/books/about/The_Classical_Theory_of_Fields.html?id=X18PF4oKyrUC&redir_esc=y), in section 31, they have proved the Poynting theorem (equation 31.6) in its integral form. In the footnote on page 76, they mention

> We assume that at the given moment there are no charges on the
>   surface itself. If this were not the case, then on the right we would
>   have to include the energy flux transported by particles passing
>   through the surface.

I would like to know how would the additional term look like, and any physical situation in which this term is important?

Comment: It's just saying that there are no charges entering or leaving the control volume, because they would be carrying kinetic energy into or out of the region.

Comment: I think there would be an additional surface integral, and the integrand probably has dimension of energy per time per area. I guess electric field, rate of change in current would be involved.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer should be such: that charge on the surface of the volume creates an electric field is equal $\vec E=4\pi \sigma \vec n$, where $\sigma$ is the surface charge and then the energy flux is $\oint c \sigma [\vec n,\vec H]df$

The charges of the electric field are formed on the surface of the dielectric, the conductor forms currents, so this member is essential for the situation with the dielectric in an external field